# Algorithms find bus route

Tags: java, algorithm

I working in my thesis, the project is support user find busline in my city in android.
So i don't know i should use what algorithm to find the busline.
I have 2 table : 
First table : BusStop:

```
BusStop_Id
BusLine_Id (connect to BusLine table)
Name
Latlng
Next_id(ID of next busstop)
```

Second table :  BusLine:

```
ID
Name
ArrayList<BusStop> (all busstop of that busline)
```

I tried many algorithm a long time but i can't complete it.
Can you tell me what's the algorithm i need?

Comment: Do you have any idea on vehicle routing problem?

Comment: first define clearly what the algorithm should do. Should it just find the nearest bus or find the best route between two points? What does "best" mean in this context? Is changing bus lines allowed?, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm.  It's pretty simple and should do the trick.  You could assign costs for things like switching bus lines, if that's allowable but undesirable.

Comment: can i use Dijkstra in directed graph?

Comment: I've only ever had to implement Dijkstra's algorithm one time, and that was an undirected graph.  However, it was my understanding that, as long as all the weights are positive numbers, you can use it with a directed graph as well.  If your graph is large, the performance will scale with the square of the number of vertices in your graph (i.e., O(n^2) time).  There are variants with more advanced data structures that can improve that though.

Comment: tks i'm going to try it